# Unable to set the border Radius to zero when the container is expanded to full screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've been trying to set my border radius to zero when the container is expanded to entire screen but there seems to be no change with my code. help me build my first flutter project!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.backgroundColor,
          borderRadius: isFull
              ? BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(0.0),
                )
              : BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(150.0),
                )),
      height: _currentHeight,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: widget.child,
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragUpdate: (a) {
              var _currentDy = a.globalPosition.dy;
              var newHeight = _currentDy;


setState(() {
                if (newHeight >= widget.minHeight) {
                  _currentHeight = newHeight;
                } else {
                  _currentHeight = widget.minHeight;
                }
                if (_currentDy == widget.height*0.9) {
                  isFull = true;
                } else {
                  isFull = false;
                }
              });
            },`
```

Comment: Did u check if `onVerticalDragUpdate` is getting called?

Comment: The dragging of the container is working perfectly fine. So I hope that onVerticalUpdate is getting called correctly.

Comment: Can you try to print something there or test in debugging mode